# Variable in for loop digits

Tags: linux, bash

How can I use variable in for loop digits?

for example:

```
num="12"
for i in {0..$num}; do
        ...
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brace expansion with variables doesn't work as one would expect (see **Appendix B** for juicy details), i.e. `{0..$num}` would only return `{0..12}` literally instead of a list of number.

Try `seq` instead like this:

```
num="12"
for i in $(seq 0 $num); do
    echo $i
done
```

---

### Appendix B: Juicy details

The [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions) saith,

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable, and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word splitting, and filename expansion.

At the time shell expands `{0..$num}` (brace expansion), `$num` isn't expanded (variable expansion) yet. The sequence expression `a..b` needs both `a` and `b` to be numbers to generate a sequence, but here we have one number and one non-number (the literal string `$num`). Failing this, the shell falls back to interpreting `{0..$num}` literally. Then variable expansion takes over, and finally we get `{0..12}`

Comment: _Brace expansion doesn't support variables_ not entirely true :)

Comment: @JS웃, yeah the wording is wrong. I added a more proper explanation.

Comment: +1 for the update and added explanation. Though minor correction, $num will get expanded after a failed `brace expansion` reporting as `{1..12}` instead of `{1..$num}` but I guess OP will now get the bigger picture.

Answer (score 2):

**`Bash`** does **brace expansion** *before* **variable expansion**, so you will get output like `{1..12}`. With use of `eval` you can get it to work.

#### Test:

```
$ num=5
$ for i in {1..$num}; do echo "$i"; done
{1..5}
$ for i in $(eval echo {1..$num}); do echo "$i"; done
1
2
3
4
5
```

**Please note:** [`eval` is **evil** in disguise.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Comment: `eval` and `evil` even sound alike!